# Changing the title of the current tab or browser window

Tags: javascript, html, dom, title, titlebar

How can I change the current title of a website that appears on the tab of a browser the way Facebook changes the title to "(1) Facebook" when you have 1 notification or message?

Answer (score 5):

Just do this...

```
document.title = 'my new title';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.title = 'new title';
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'new title';
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
document.title = 'my title';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title = "your title";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "Your Desired Title"
```

**OR**

**HTML:**

```
<title id="page-title"></title>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("page-title").innerHTML = "Your Desired Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way

```
$("title").html("your title");
```